# what is the difference between isNaN and Number.isNaN?

Tags: javascript

what is the difference between isNaN and Number.isNaN?

```
isNaN('hello world'); // returns 'true'.
Number.isNaN('hello world'); // returns 'false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spec is a good place to turn for this kind of subtlety. [`isNaN`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-isnan-number) tries to convert its argument to a number; [`Number.isNaN`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-number.isnan) doesn't, it returns false if the type of its argument isn't `"number"`. So:

```js
console.log(isNaN("%"));        // true, coerced to number and result was NaN
console.log(Number.isNaN("%")); // false, not coerced
```